# What is a good way to produce side text on pages?

Tags: rotating

I'm looking for a flexible way to produce side text on pages similar to the attached picture.

Side text should respect page sizes and be multirow like the one on the picture. Also there are should be something like \hfill to produce appropriate spaces.

This example was made with tabular+multirow+sideways which isn't flexible at all.

Is there any more appropriate solutions to this problem?

[image: Side text desired example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
 \node[anchor=west] at (current page.west) {\rotatebox{270}{\parbox{\textheight}{\lipsum[1]}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works great!) Some additional remarks to your answer. Rotation angle should be 90 instead of 270. Linebreaks through "\\" and \hfill works perfectly inside! To move position a little bit from page edge it's nice to use additional optional argument "xshift=0.2cm" in \node[...] command. And finally I find out that for correct size in \textheight tikzpicture environment should be placed somewhere in between page code (I mean not very start)